# UIActivityViewController from within an HTML5 iPad App

Tags: ios, html, uiactivityviewcontroller

I built an HTML5 App specifically for the iPad.  One issue that I'm having is "printing" a page to a PDF.  One solution that works well when I'm testing the App as a regular webpage within the mobile Safari is the App "To PDF"; however, that requires one to use the UIActivityViewController to bring up access to the that App.  In earlier versions, it showed up within AirPrint as a printer, but that is no longer available.

So, my question is: Is there some functionality within HTML/javascript/jquery (or some library) that could bring up the UIActivityViewController from within an HTML5 app?

Comment: Oh you're making a web app. And the answer is NO, you can't summon `UIActivityViewController` via HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can use "jqueryprintpage" to print a page in HTML:

https://github.com/ianoxley/jqueryprintpage#readme

And you can use [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) too, if you want to create a pdf file:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Comment: As I understand this, it only prints the page.  I can print the page with a standard print command.  That's not the issue.  It's creating a PDF from the current page and outputting it to an external source (i.e. email, php script, etc).

Comment: Michael, sorry but I understand that do you need some  HTML/javascript/jquery library to printing the current page. If you want to ouputting the content into a email maybe you can use jsPDF and mailto see my answer edited.

Comment: As I understand it, you can't add an attachment using mailto.

Comment: Yes it's not possible attach a file. At first I thought that you only needed a javascript library to print. I try to find a solution and as I can read it's impossible to print the way you would like to do. If you find a solution please share it. Sorry I could't help you, I worked very little with IOS ( always native)...